# How to get Sum of Group in last row of group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my sample data:

```
ID  Prod  Price 
----------------
01  Vios  150
01  Vios  120
02  Copax 100
02  Copax 200
```

Desire result is:

```
ID   Prod   Price  Total
------------------------
01  Vios    150        0
01  Vios    120      270
02  Copax   100        0
02  Copax   200      300
```

Comment: How do you know which row is the last?

Comment: Can we just add a row for the totals?  `SELECT ID, PRod, sum(Price) From table group by Grouping Sets ((ID, PRod), (ID,Prod,Price))`

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: or use sum() window function for a running total `Select ID, Prod, price, sum(Price) over (partition by ID, Prod Order by ID, Prod, Price) as RunningTotal
From Example`

Comment: Please post the query you have so far.

Comment: @HABO  Thanks for the detail info, I will take care next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by arbitrarily deciding on a last row - the "order by Prod" within the over clause could be anything. Also the order of the prices within each id will be arbitrary - so if its important that the 100 comes before the 200 then you'll need some other field to provide a meaningful order

```
create table #data
(
    ID int,
    Prod varchar(5),
    Price int
);

insert into #data values(1,'Vios',150);
insert into #data values(1,'Vios',120);
insert into #data values(2,'Copax',100);
insert into #data values(2,'Copax',200);

with cte as (
    select ID, 
        Prod, 
        Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by Prod) rn,
        sum(Price) over (partition by ID order by Prod) total
    from #data
)
select ID,
    Prod,
    Price,
    case when rn = 1 then total else 0 end
from cte
order by ID,
    rn desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;WITH d(SeqNo,ID,Prod,Price)AS(
        SELECT 1,1,'Vios',150 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2,1,'Vios',120 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3,2,'Copax',100 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4,2,'Copax',200 
      )
      SELECT ID,Prod,Price,SUM(Price)OVER(PARTITION BY Prod ORDER BY SeqNo) AS Total FROM d
      ORDER BY d.SeqNo
```

Result sets

```
ID          Prod  Price       Total
----------- ----- ----------- -----------
1           Vios  150         150
1           Vios  120         270
2           Copax 100         100
2           Copax 200         300
```